# adding tooltips to line plots in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there any way at the moment to add constant tooltips to a bokeh line plot in python? I did not find anything about it in the documention.

I am looking for a way to allow adding the tooltip interactively ala matlab. However, doing so via the code at first is acceptable.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (as of 0.8.1) the line glyph does not support hit testing, so it does not support a hover tool, either. However, if it suffices to have a hover tooltip on just the "points" of the line, then several people have uses a second set of transparent markers located at the same points as a workaround. Something like:

```
line(x, y)
circle(x, y, size=8, alpha=0)
```

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1486) for adding line hit testing, it should hopefully been in one of the next few releases.

Comment: thanks, i've figured out that workaround. But this is not actually my question. I am looking mostly at adding a permanent tooltip and not one on hover. More like an interactive version of annotations in matplotlib. This is mainly used to mark interesting points for other viewers.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Static tooltip annotations are planned but not currently implemented (as of Bokeh 0.8.1).

Comment: thanks. matplotlib is not interactive enough to replace matlab for me. Bokeh looks like its right on track. plot.ly is there but I can't use it offline...